# Render Object on the basis of selection from dropdown options in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to react, my problem is, I have one dropdown in which there are two options **A** and **B**, 
Example: As shown below this is my dropdown display options dynamically in my case options are A and B.

```
  <DropDown
    selectedData={Options}
  />
```

Custom DropDown:

```
  const onChange = (value) => {
    !isMulti && setToggle(!toggle);
    onChecked(value);
  }

const createOptions = () => {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      return data.map(({ value}, index) => {
        if (isMulti) {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input type="checkbox"
                onChange={() => onChange(value)}
                checked={selectedOrNot(value)}
              />
            </div>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <div key={index}
              onClick={() => onSelectionChange(value)}
            </div>
          );
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      return <div>No data found</div>
    }
  }
```

Also, I have JSON data which consists of two objects in it. for eg:

```
data: {
        A: {
            num1: "0.241",
            num2: "15.293",
        },
        B: {
            num1: "0.241",
            num2: "15.293",
        },
    }
```

So what I want is whenever users select **A** as an option from dropdown it will render A object eg: data.A. Similarly when users select **B** as an option it will render B object eg: data.B.
Please help.

Comment: Did you create the Dropdown component ? What do you mean by render data A ?

Comment: Yes @sidali i have created the drop-down. What I mean to say is i have show object A on Ui if users selects option A and if user selects B as an option i want toh data for object B in place of A.

Comment: I think you will have to use a sort of onChange function, can edit your post and add you Dropdown component code

Comment: Added the code for dropdown @sidali

Comment: is your `data` an object? because you can only `.map()` an array of objects `const data = [{num1: "...", num2: "..."}, {num1: "...", num2: "..."}]`

Comment: yes it is an array of objects. @teddybeard

Comment: pinged you on Gitter